# Convert Json string to List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting a string with json objects from an external webapi. I have a code that gets the objects into a ExpandoObject list, but there must be another solution without using dynamic object.

Here is the code:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = 

(System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/api/users.json");
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "API key="+somekey;
// Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
//response from the api
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
//serialize the data
var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
System.Collections.IList users = (System.Collections.IList)((IDictionary<string, object>)((IDictionary<string, object>)jss.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer))["data"])["users"];

List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> api_users = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>();
//putting the expandable objects in list
foreach (var u in users)
{
    var user = ((Dictionary<string, object>)((IDictionary<string, object>)u)["User"]);
    dynamic data = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    //putting the user attributes into dynamic object
    foreach (var prop in user)
    {
        ((IDictionary<String, Object>)data).Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
    }
    api_users.Add(data);
}
```

Here is a sample of the json string:

```
"data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "User": {
          "user_id": "6741",
          "email": "mail@mail.com",
          "first_name": "Mark",
          "last_name": "Plas",
          "street_address": "",
          "post_code": "",
          "city": ""
        },
        "CreatedBy": {
          "id": null,
          "name": null
        },
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "id": null,
          "name": null
        }
      },...(can have more users here)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the many C# JSON parsers to do this. I personally prefer [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (which you can install via NuGet). It can deserialize to both dynamic objects as well as to your own statically-typed classes.

Comment: I don't want to use external libraries, if that's possible